# Is Matlab graph() compatible in Octave?

Tags: matlab, graph, octave, compatibility

I am trying to run Matlab code in Octave. It is throwing up an error for this code meant to create an undirected graph:

```
G = graph(Matrix~=0,'lower');
```

saying:

```
"warning: the 'graph' function is not yet implemented in Octave"
```

Does the graph function exist in Octave, and if not, is there an equivalent function I can substitute?

Comment: No, `graph` objects are even relatively new for MATLAB and have not been implemented in Octave. Depending on what you're trying to do, you may be able to find implementations of specific graph algorithms in file exchange.

Comment: @beaker if he's using Octave he cannot use File Exchange since Matlab central Terms of Use [forbid it](http://wiki.octave.org/FAQ#Why_can.27t_I_use_code_from_File_Exchange_in_Octave.3F_It.27s_released_under_a_BSD_license.21).

Comment: @carandraug Interesting. I guess I never bothered to read that.